# ReferenceError: resolve is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a function to call the google speech API. Looks all is good but I cannot find why it is giving me the error. I am a beginner with node and promises so not sure why this error appears.

> ReferenceError: resolve is not defined at index.js:57

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
  return speech
    .longRunningRecognize(responses)
    .then(function(results) {
      var operation = responses[0];
      console.log("Operation: ", operation);
      return operation.promise();
    })
    .then(function(responses) {
      resolve(responses[0]);
      console.log("Result: ", JSON.stringify(responses[0]));
    })
```

Where the promise

> operation.promise() (line 57)

cannot be resolved. It wants to resolve
the promise, but it looks like it cannot find the resolve function.

The Google API works like this:

- First, you do an api call to upload your data and start the process.
- This gives you back an operation name.
- This name should be used subsequently to get the result when the result is ready (only takes max 30 sec)

I have the feeling it's all working, the call is made, the response comes back. The code waits and then it wants to resolve but it cannot...

My code is like this (its a cloud function)

```
  exports.transcribeAudio = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  const object = event.data;
  const filePath = object.name;
  const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
  const fileBucket = object.bucket;
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  // Get the file name.
  //const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  console.log(filePath + " name: " + fileName);
  // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
  if (!filePath.startsWith("ucl-flac-audio")) {
    console.log("Only flac-audio need to be converted");
    return true;
  }
  // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
  if (object.resourceState === "not_exists") {
    console.log("This is a deletion event.");
    return true;
  }

  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      const audioFilename = "gs://" + fileBucket + "/" + filePath;
      console.log(audioFilename);
      const request = {
        config: {
          encoding: "FLAC",
          languageCode: "fr-FR"
        },
        audio: {
          uri: audioFilename
        }
      };

      return speech
        .longRunningRecognize(request)
        .then(function(responses) {
          var operation = responses[0];
          console.log("Operation: ", operation);
          return operation.promise();
        })
        .then(function(responses) {
          resolve(responses[0]);
          console.log("Result: ", JSON.stringify(responses[0]));
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.error("Failed to get transcript.", err);
          //    reject(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're already in a .then callback. Just `return responses[0]`, and the promise created by .then will resolve to that value.

Comment: btw, this: `.catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });` is completely pointless. Just delete these lines.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't call `resolve()` from within a `.then()` handler.  There is no such function defined there.  If you want to set the resolved value of the promise from within a `.then()` handler, you can just return that value.

Change this:

```
.then(function(responses) {
      resolve(responses[0]);
      console.log("Result: ", JSON.stringify(responses[0]));
})
```

to this:

```
.then(function(responses) {
      console.log("Result: ", JSON.stringify(responses[0]));
      return responses[0];
})
```

---

FYI, the `resolve()` you are likely thinking of is an argument to the new Promise executor callback:

```
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(10);
});
```

And, this is the context in which you would use it.

Comment: Thank you that explains the problem! Can I then just in that return write it to a google cloud bucket? Something like 'return bucket
        .file(filename)
        .save(JSON.stringify(responses[0])) or is that an async action as well and I should use something like return new Promise(resolve,reject) etc

Comment: @Koen - I don't know that Google API. If `bucket.file(...).save(...)` returns a promise, then you can just return it from within a `.then()` handler.  If not, you need to promisify it first.

Comment: @jsfriend00 Thanks! I just added it in the return and all works beautifully now! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Before using `resolve` you need to pass the `resolve` as argument:

In this case,

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.post('YOUR URL HERE', params)
                .then(response => {                    
                    resolve() // Here you can use resolve as it passed as argument
                })
});
```

Note: You can use GET, POST for the axios call

Comment: Exactly , even I ran into same error , I forgot to create new promise for the `axios.post` , now I understood perfectly , thank you